# How to show a hidden button on a modal after ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to show a hidden button after a ajax success, but I have not been able to do it. Any help will be greatly appreciate it. Thanks for your time.

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        success: function (data) {
            // alert(data);
            disable_enable_features('resetForm');
            console.log(data);
            $('.modal-title-message').html(''); 
            $('.modal-body-message').html('Some text'); 
            $('#closeModal').show();
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');

        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        timeout: 45000
    });
```

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <span id="closeModal" hidden>
     <button  type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

give and id to button then:

`$('#buttonId').show();`

UPDATE:

other option:

```
$('#exampleButton').css("display", "none"); // for hide
$('#exampleButton').css("display", ""); // for show
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to button, etc "exampleButton"
Then on success do:

```
$("#exampleButton").show()
```

update

Answer (score 0):

You do the right thing :

```
$('#closeModal').show(); //this correctly undoes your hide
```

Your problem probably comes from somewhere else, are you sure you're getting into your function?

You should use your browser's debugging console and set breakpoints.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting into the function. Just tried with a console.log and is working fine, but still I'm not able to show the button.